# Verify whether or not a subset is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I came across this subset

$U=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\vert x+y+z\geq0\}$.

I know I have to check this subset by three steps. I suspect it is not a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ since it may not be closed under scalar multiplication if the scalar is negative. I'm still unsure about my judgement as I'm barely a newbie in Linear Algebra. So hopefully someone can help me out!
Thank you!

Comment: Your suspicion is correct. What are you unsure about?

Comment: @Vim Just getting started in Linear Algebra so I dont really have much confidence in solving these :)

Comment: any subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is either $(0,0,0)$ or lines passing through origin or planes passing through origin..

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. For example, $(1,1,1)$ is a member of $U$, but $(-1)\cdot(1,1,1)$ is not.